# Trying to create a search bar and I need to be able to select a specific category and link it to items in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

Cannot get this code to work it always gives me the ERROR message. Something is wrong with the query but i cannot figure it out. Do I add more query into the coding or do I have unnecessary coding?

```
<html>    
<div>
    <form action="" method = "post">
        Search for items with: 
        <select value = "CategoryCriteria">
            <option value = "NULL">Select</option>
            <option value = "book">Book</option>
            <option value = "furniture">Furniture</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</div>  
    <?php
    require 'authentication.inc';
    echo $_POST['CategoryCriteria']; 
    if ($_POST['CategoryCriteria'] != "NULL") {
        // connect to the server
        $connection = sqlsrv_connect( $hostName, $connectionInfo )
            or die("ERROR: selecting database server failed");

        // gather information
        $Category = $_POST['CategoryCriteria'];
        echo $Category;

        // prepare SQL query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE Category= '$Category'";


        // check out the query
        echo "Query: ".$query."<br>";

        // Execute SQL query
        $query_result = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query)
            or die( "ERROR: Query is wrong");

        echo "<table border=1>";
        echo "<tr>";

        // fetch attribute names
        foreach( sqlsrv_field_metadata($query_result) as $fieldMetadata)
            echo "<th>".$fieldMetadata['Name']."</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        // fetch table records
        while ($line = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tr>\n";
            foreach ($line as $cell) {
                echo "<td> $cell </td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        // close the connection with database
        sqlsrv_close($connection);
    }
?>
    <a href = "search.php"><button>Back</button></a>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you paste error message?

Comment: I got the table working! I just had to change the Select values to select name in the query but; now it still gives me the error of bookQuery: SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE Category= 'book'

Comment: Apart of the OP, it's not good to do this `require 'authentication.inc';`, instead use `require 'authentication.inc.php';` or `require 'authentication.php';` because if you type the url of the `whatever.inc` it will expose your `php` code if you view its source, unlike `whatever.php` which only shows the output data

Comment: I see what you mean, but i am not really concerned about the security part since it  just needs to be a simple website. But i really do appreciate the information for future references!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your have "value in the select tag:

```
<select value = "CategoryCriteria">
            <option value = "NULL">Select</option>
            <option value = "book">Book</option>
            <option value = "furniture">Furniture</option>
        </select>
```

Should be:

```
<select name = "CategoryCriteria">
            <option value = "NULL">Select</option>
            <option value = "book">Book</option>
            <option value = "furniture">Furniture</option>
        </select>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked with using  name instead of value but after getting the item list from the search but it still gives me the bookQuery: SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE Category= 'book' message on top of the table.

Comment: @YusufYılmaz you have this `echo $Category;` and this `echo "Query: ".$query."<br>";` in your code

Comment: Both of those were provided to me by the professor and he would not let me change any off them.. Do they effect each other? Is that why I get the SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE Category= 'book' message?

Comment: These two lines are responsible for outputting this `bookQuery: SELECT * FROM ITEM WHERE Category= 'book' message`

Comment: Ohhh now I get it. I think the reason why it is there is to be a representative of the function that I used to get it work. Thanks a lot for the help, highly appreciated!